# 3D points projected to form an image

Tags: image, 3d, 2d, projection, perspective

I want your intellectual suggestions for a problem i have. I have 3D points data along with intensity field `(x,y,z,I)` which represent the 3D scene. I want this 3D data converted into an image (2D matrix with intensity values `'I'`).

I plan to do perspective projection of 3D points using pinhole camera model ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model)).

`x'=f*x/z`  and `y'=f*y/z`

What value should I select for `'f'`? How is the size of image dependent on it? (say I need an image of size 500*500 , what value will suit for `'f'`)

Since coordinates in 2D image are integers, how should I quantize `x'` and `y'` values and substitute the corresponding intensity value? E.g. if I get two sets(by using `f=10`) as

```
x,y,z,I
(3,1,2,128) -> x',y',I(15,5,128)
(3.1,1.1,2,150) -> (15.5,5.5,150)
```

Of the above two sets, should i just round off the `x'` and `y'` values and use its intensity at that coordinate or should I use an average of intensity of the non-integer coordinates ?

Will the resulting image be clearly depicting the scene in 2D (like a photo taken from a camera)?

Shall pay much gratitude for your ideas. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what exactly are you trying to project a what exactly should be the result, but the most 'basic' projection to `xy` plane (you just 'forget' the `z` coordinate) would not work for your data?

Comment: I am trying to project 3D point(x,y,z) onto 2D plane(x,y) of a particular size(width*height). This 2D plane is the image which i want. I would put the image values to be intensity value present in data(x,y,z,I). My problem is if two or more 3D points lead to non integer coordinates ,how to convert them to integer coordinates so that intensity of 3D point could be substituted in 2D image coordinate(integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you use the average intensity or nearest neighbour or other kinds of interpolation depends on your application. OpenGL for instance, when it does this operation, gives you the option of choosing (see GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER and GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER).

I suggest you try different approaches and see what they look like; the difference between linear and nearest neighbour interpolation is one line of code. More information about your intended application would probably be helpful.

Algorithmically the simplest approach to doing the projection is not necessarily the most computationally efficient. It is much easier to code this if rather than projecting the points the process would start with the 2D pixel location, find the corresponding nearby 3D points and perform interpolation (even if just nearest neighbour interpolation) to get the intensity. This will stop you from having e.g. gaps in the image and you no longer have to worry about having interpolation because of magnification as well as spaces between pixels.

How to project the data again depends on what you are trying to achieve so some more information about the application would be useful - e.g. are you trying to fit all of the points into the image? Or are you trying to fill the image? Or is there some property of the cloud that makes it likely to be squeezable into a square if projected? If it was collected by an image array then it should be possible to project it easily (and much of the above mechanics unnecessary since it should be easy to recover the original coordinates). Otherwise there are likely to be points that don't turn up in the image or parts of the image that don't have corresponding points.

If I make some assumptions then I can solve the projection equation for the limits. If we assume a 640 x 480 image and that the centre of projection is at the centre of the image then we have:

```
x'=f*x/z + 320
```

(note that this is misuing the focal length as is commonly done to map onto pixels where the true model has it mapping onto the scale of the image array and thereafter into pixels).

Let `greatestx:x` be the largest `x` value in the point array and `greatestx:z` the corresponding `z` value for that point then

```
639.5=f*greatestx:x/greatestx:z + 320
```

So,

```
f = 319.5*greatestx:z / greatestx:x
```

If you do this for the smallest x value, smallest y value, and largest y value:

```
f = -319.5*smallestx:z / smallestx: x

f = 239.5*greatesty:z / greatesty: y

f = -239.5*smallesty:z / smallesty: y
```

Now if we choose the smallest `f` of the above then we guarantee the point cloud to fit into the image (but there might be gaps). If we choose the largest `f` then we guarantee there to be no gaps in the image (but there might be parts that don't fit onto the image).

Comment: Thank you D.J.Duff, u have given a clear idea. So, if I get x=1.2,y=2 and for another as x=1.4,y=2.3 I would substitute the average intensity of both at x=1,y=2(round off). After the entire operation if there are gaps in the image as u pointed out,what should I do to fill those? Should I just filter the image with an averaging box filter ?? but doesnt that cause the edges to blur as well??

Comment: U suggest that to find the nearby 3d points to a 2d pixel, how to find the neighboring 3d points to a pixel?

Comment: The most efficient way to find the neighbours to a point depends on the structure of the data in general. To find the neighbours to a 3D pixel a fairly general way is to place the pixels into a binary search tree or KD-Tree or similar. The Point Cloud Library (PCL) should already have the algorithms you need to do this. However, if the data is distributed roughly over a grid, 2D pigeon sort should work well to get at points efficiently. However, depending on your application, brute search may be sufficient (what are your processing time requirements?).

Comment: Try nearest neighbour interpolation first and see how it looks. Because I do not know your application I do not know what you need. And now I see your point about linear interpolation; since your points are not regular it won't be straightforward to do it the normal way. So if nearest neighbour is not good I suggest using a radial basis function approach for the interpolation (use a triangular function to begin with).

Comment: Thank you D.J.Duff. My application is to map similar objects in the two images. One is the ordinary jpg image of scene and other is the image formed out of pointcloud of that scene. It wont be possible to do processing in image(using opencv) and pointcloud(using pcl) and integrate them. So it would be better if i convert pointcloud to image right?? In creating image from pointcloud, I tried nearest neigbour and i get a lot of gaps between pixels(though the objects in scene are distinguishable). How to fill these gaps?? Also I should not knowingly fill pixels which are meant to be gaps..

Comment: How are you acquiring the point cloud? I think this is important because it may already be naturally structured.

Comment: Regarding nearest neighbour. Actually if you have gaps it probably means that you have a radius limit on your nearest neighbour otherwise all gaps should be filled: the only gaps that should stay are ones near the edge of the image and for that you can do some postprocessing - e.g. label each pixel according to the ID of its contributing point and flood fill away from the corners and edges all the ones that are originating from the same point.

Comment: But if you are just going to run recognition algorithms over it it may not be necessary to bother with the postprocessing. Also, whether you use PCL or OpenCV or etc depends on what algorithms you will use to do the object recognition.

Comment: If there are real gaps in the point cloud then the only way you will detect them is by checking how far away the nearest point is anyway right? I see that you may want to do more sophisticated interpolation in that case but it is unclear how much it will help object recognition. You could try radial basis function interpolation if you think it will help with the recognition.